Finder Error Code -8076 when selecting tagged files via the keyboard in column view?
Steps to reproduce:

Find or create two or more files in Finder.
View as columns (command-3 or click the command in the menu bar).
Tag the first file (control click and add a color).
Select the files via the keyboard (hold shift and press downarrow key).

Observed behavior:

An alert pops up warning: “The operation can’t be completed because [FILENAME] is in use. An unexpected error (error -8076). OK”

Expected behavior:

Nothing should happen.

How do I solve this? I am the only user of my computer. I have full permissions. I created the files. This happens on multiple Macs running macOS Sonoma 14.7 and Sequoia 15.0.


What version of macOS, please.

14.7                            Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.

You can always find the version of macOS in a tag, or simply type - "The version of macOS is Sonoma" or something similar.

The tags simply contain a color and the color name. I do not know where they would include the OS version number.

That's not what I mean. If you look at your question, there's a section between the question body and the 'Share Edit Follow Close Flag' links.  There you can edit the tags to indicate the version of macOS. You've already added keyboard, finder, error, and alert. I added sonoma for you so you see what I mean.

I’ve now confirmed it happens in Sequoia also, so I’m removing the version-specific tag.
